# Is there a FOSS macro somewhere that will convert tabs to the spaces up to the next tab mark?

Tags: email, microsoft-word, macros

Would like to ensure text documents don't get mangled by badly behaving email clients on smart phones that mangle tabs, so would want to convert tabs to the number of spaces up to the next tab mark in Word or similar wordprocessor. Is there a solution out there?

Comment: Should the end result be a (pain text) email or a Wrod document suitable as an attachment?

Comment: Plain text. But can just be copied and pasted.

Comment: Interesting idea, but the problem with this is that unless you're using a monospace font, it's going to depend entirely on what font the text is being displayed in. Different systems (and different text editors) have different default fonts for plain text, so if you need to insert 8 spaces in Arial, you might need to enter 10 in Calibri or only 4 in Courier.

Answer (score 0):

email software affects the main mail body, and not the attachment if you are sending your file as an attachment.

To be doubly sure that the file is not getting changed in between, you can convert to pdf and send as attachment .